# Differences between pgfplots and tkz-fct plots

Tags: pgfplots, tkz-fct

I am trying to choose between `pgfplots` and `tkz-fct` for producing beautiful graphs in LaTeX. It seems `tkz-fct` graphs look better with less effort (fewer lines of code) compared to `pgfplots`. The [documentation for tkz-fct](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-fct) isn't English however, so I am struggling with finding how to draw things like horizontal and vertical lines, points, holes, etc. which I know how to draw in `pgfplots`. Because of the language barrier, I am leaning toward using `pgfplots` for my plots. However, I want to know what else one should consider when deciding between the two systems.

As an experiment, I tried producing the same plot using both systems and compared the results:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=.75 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,color,srcltx,thmtools}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid, height=10cm,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
xtick={-5,-4,...,5}, ytick={-40,-30,...,40},
xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-40, ymax=40,
]
\addplot[domain=-5:5, samples=100, mark=none, thick, blue]{-3*x^4+6*x^3+9*x^2-24*x+12};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-40,ymax=40,ystep=10]  
\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[color=blue, thick, domain=-5:5]{-3*x**4+6*x**3+9*x**2-24*x+12};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The graphs look mostly the same, except better positions of the  `x` and `y` labels from `tkz-fct`.

It seems like this `pgfplots` requires writing more manual specifications to get a good-looking picture (e.g. if you don't specify the number of samples, you'll get a jaggedly-drawn graph), while `tkz-fct` is a bit more automatic.

Currently `pgfplots` is throwing an error `Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} into your preamble."` However the code still compiles, so this isn't a complete deal-breaker for me (I'm probably just doing something wrong.)

On the other hand, there's a [breaking incompatibility with `tkz-fct` and `thmtools`, as this question discusses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211176/conflict-between-tkz-fct-and-thmtools). This issue, combined with the lack of English documentation, make me lean toward using `pgfplots` for my graphs.

Are there any downsides to using `pgfplots` relative to `tkz-fct` I should keep in mind, before counting out `tkz-fct`? What should one consider when choosing between packages? What are the relative strengths of each, and relative disadvantages? Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: You should really add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` to the preamble, or, even better, update your LaTeX installation, the current version is `1.16`. May I ask what precisely your question is? IMHO there is nothing what tkz-fct can do which cannot be done by pgfplots, but the converse is not true AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, `pgfplots` is very careful with that. The author makes major effort to make sure the package is downward compatible while improving it. For instance, in older versions you need to add `axis cs:` if you want to synchronize `tikz` paths with the axis coordinates, in newer versions this is no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to force Overleaf to update its `pgfplots` installation from 1.15 to 1.16 for my projects?

Comment: I don't know. But 1.15 is certainly better than the no version. If you use `xmin=-5.5, xmax=5.5, ymin=-45, ymax=45,` in your pgfplots plot, it looks already similar to the output you seem to prefer.

Comment: @Mathemanic No way to force an update, but you can write to their customer service (click on the "Help" button) explaining your problem. It's probable they can solve your specific problem, usually they are very quick in replying.

Comment: You could turn your question into something that is more straightforward to answer if you either ask how to achieve a specific output with `pgfplots`, or how to make sure that all your plots have certain features (answer will probably be something like `\pgfplotsset{every axis.... some key words here ...}`, or examples of the kind "can be only done with pgfplots/tkz-fct".

Comment: I'm not so much looking for answers on how to fix the axis labels. I'm more-so looking for an answer that details "benefits of `tkz-fct` over `pgfplots` are [...], limitations are [...]"

Comment: In a way, your question is then very similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39868/121799. (I personally would like to mention that there are only 28 posts tagged tikz-fct and 6532 are tagged pggfplots. I personally share the opinion that is reflected by that public vote.)

Comment: With overleaf you can use the updated version of any package  just by downloading it from ctan then uploading it to your project in overleaf. But take it with great care as there might be incompatibilities with other not updated packages.